# How can I find metadata of BigQuery Model

Tags: sql, machine-learning, google-bigquery

I know that we can get schema information of tables using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. Is there a similar method for BigQuery Models?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/getting-model-metadata

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect everything related to the evaluation metrics by using ML.EVALUATE

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-evaluate-overview

The ML.TRIAL_INFO function is used to display information regarding trials from a hyperparameter tuning model.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-trial-info

And there are many other functions to inspect a model using SQL, you can learn more about them here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference#bigquery-ml-standard-sql-reference

Answer (score 0):

BQML doesn't support information schema for Models yet.